# Definition of one function going to zero faster than other function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Let $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0=\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$. Now I want to say which function goes to zero faster as x approaches zero. I have seen in a post that the accepted definition is: if $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$ then we say f goes to zero faster than g as x approaches a.

Is this the definition? Isn't it a way to check the statement rather than a definition?

I was thinking the following:
We say f goes to zero faster than g going to zero (as x approaches a) if $\exists \delta>0$ such that $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $0<|x-a|<\delta$ we have $|f(x)|<|g(x)|$ (I don't know if this is correct, I tried it on my own).

This captures the idea that as we are going closer and closer to a, the distance between f(x) and 0 is becoming less and less when compared to distance between g(x) and 0.

Now if $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$ then it is easy to see that $\exists \delta>0$ such that $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $0<|x-a|<\delta$ we have $|f(x)|<|g(x)|$.

Hence the limit definiton is actually a way to check which goes faster.

Am I thinking Correctly? Is there any mistake in the definition which I thought of?

Comment: Look at $f(x)=\frac 12 g(x)$ to see why you are wrong.

Comment: It depends on what you really mean. I would phrase your suggestion just as "if $x$ is close enough to $a$, then (the absolute value of) $f$ is smaller than $g$" which doesn't sound like what you want.

Comment: Okay. So what is the correct definition then?

Comment: The definition in your first paragraph is the accepted definition.

Comment: Okay @geetha290krm